# KendoGrid filtering breaks when <thead> template is applied

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a simple KendoUI control that filters as expected when only row templates are applied:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#kendo-grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [
            { name: "Jane", age: 18 },
            { name: "John", age: 20 }
        ],
    filterable: true,      
    rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
    altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#altRowTemplate").html())
 });
});
```

However, as soon as I specify a header template (by using a table instead of a div) the filtering seems to break:

```
<table id="kendo-grid">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>age</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/xigaciti/2/edit?html,js,output

What is the correct usage to apply an HTML header template to this type of grid?

Please note that I can't use the columns array to specify headers because this kendoGrid is embedded in an MVC application and I need Razor access to our Resource files from the View (to swap out column names when the user sets another language), hence the need for HTML templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the `<th>` tags to `<td>`, it seems to have resolved the issue.  I'm not sure why, but at least this is a work around for you.

```
<table id="kendo-grid">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>age</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the reason this works is because when you use <td> it breaks and the template is no longer applied. Try changing the names inside of the <td> and you will be see the changes are not picked up.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do it just yet.  I wonder if you could use jQuery to change the column headers?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with KendoUI so I thought about a different implementation (using a custom filter) and came up with this client-side search box:

```
<input type="search" id="search-grid" value="Enter text to find" />
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xigaciti/15/edit?html,js,output

Note that the integers in the DataSource are now strings (so we can use the 'contains' operator):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#kendo-grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: [
                    { name: "Jane", age: "14" },
                    { name: "John", age: "25" },
                    { name: "Jenny", age: "36" },
                    { name: "David", age: "47" },
                    { name: "Paul", age: "58" },
                    { name: "Michael", age: "69" }
                ]
            },
            filterable: false,
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
            altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#altRowTemplate").html())
        });

     $("#search-grid").focus(function () {
            $(this).val('');
        });

     $("#search-grid").keyup(function () {
            var val = $('#search-grid').val();
            $("#kendo-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
                logic: "or",
                filters: [
                    {
                        field: "name",
                        operator: "contains",
                        value: val
                    },
                    {
                        field: "age",
                        operator: "contains",
                        value: val
                    }
                ]
            });
        });                  
    });
```